# Visual Basic Iterating Over a ListBox with an Event Listener

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a ListBox Containg a list of items,i am wondering how would i create a handler which can Iterate the ListBox whenever an event is happen.
I have the Following Code to read a file into a listbox.

```
Private Sub Load_File_To_ListBox(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Load_File_To_ListBox.Click
    Dim r As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\resu\Desktop\test.txt")
    While (r.Peek() > -1)
        lb1.Items.Add(r.ReadLine)
    End While
    r.Close()
End Sub
```

Here is my event handler code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = " "
    TextBox1.Text &= ListBox1.SelectedItems.Item(i).ToString
    i = i + 1
End Sub
```

`i` is declared  as a global variable to keep track of the next item In the `ListBox`.   What I want is to read the next item from the `Listbox` and put it into the `TextBox` whenever Button2 is Clicked.

Kindly help me in modifying my code to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem lies with the following line of code:

```
'This line of code looks at all of the items that have been 
'selected in the list box, and out of all of the selected 
'items it will select the item at index i.
TextBox1.Text &= ListBox1.SelectedItems.Item(i).ToString
```

Because the code is looking at ***selected items only*** and not ***all items*** the code is not behaving as you would expect. Instead, use the following line of code:

```
TextBox1.Text &= ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()
```